# Sending Jquery value to PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm really struggling to get this working so any help would be much appreciated!

Basically I have a JQGRid that displays bookings with double click event as follows:

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {
        rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
                    var brData = rowData['bookref'];

        getGridRow(brData);
    },
```

This gets passed to getGridRow function:

```
function getGridRow(brData) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'bookings-dialog.php',
      data: {'rowdata' : brData },
      dataType: 'json', //this is what we expect our returned data as
     error: function(){
                    alert("It failed");
                    $('#cp-div-error').html('');
                    $('#cp-div-error').append('<p>There was an error inserting the data, please try again later.</p>');
                    $('#cp-div-error').dialog('open');
             },
      success: function(data){
        //empty our dialog so we don't end up with duplicate content
        $('.cp-booking-info').empty();
        //we have told the browser to expect JSON back, no need to do any parsing
        //the date
        $('.cp-booking-info').append('<p class="pno-margin">Booking Date: '+data.bookref+'</p>');

        //now let's manipulate our dialog and open it.
        $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({
          show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
          hide: 'slide',
          height: 625,
          width: 733,
          title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ brData
        });
      }

    });
```

And this is the bookings-dialog.php:

```
<?php

require_once('deployment.php');
require_once('bootstrp/all.inc.php');
require_once('models/sql.php');
require_once('models/bookingdocket.php');

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {
           $rowdata = $_POST['rowdata'];

           $query = ("SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'");

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

           BookingDocket::set_id($row['id']);
           BookingDocket::set_bookref($row['bookref']);
           BookingDocket::set_bookdate($row['bookingdate']);
           BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);
           BookingDocket::set_journeytype($row['journeytype']);
           BookingDocket::set_passtel($row['passengertel']);
           BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);

           $booking_ref = BookingDocket::get_bookref();


           return json_encode(array('bookref' => $booking_ref,
                                    )
                             );




        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
    }

    $dbh = null;





?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title Work</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jq-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jq-grid/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/utils/util-sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jq-core/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jq-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jq-grid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jq-grid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/interface-datagrids.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/image-preload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/general-interface.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/general-controlpanel.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/general-validation.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="cp-bookings-dialog">
  <div class="cp-tiles-wrapper-dlg">
    <div class="cp-booking-info left">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when you double click a booking, the booking reference (e.g. `BR12345`) is passed to bookings-dialog.php and used in the the query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'`). I have been trying to use JSON to achieve this but at the moment when I double click a row, it is just failing at the moment and I am unsure why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is failing? Apart from that you need to bind your variables, now you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: By default the type of `request` when you dont specify it in ajax is `GET` but in your `.php` script you're using `POST`. specify the `type` to `post`

Comment: The data being returned is coming back as 'unspecefied' any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default HTTP type for AJAX calls is a GET.  You should change to a POST.

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
...
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',  //ADD THIS .ajax defaults to GET and in the php you expect POST
      url: 'bookings-dialog.php',
      data: {'rowdata' : brData },
```